# Section list item update renders all the section list items

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-functional-component

I have a section list that shows a list of items, each item is a component itself and contains a checkbox and some other views. The checkbox is not visible at first. long pressing on any of the items will make the checkboxes visible.

**The issue**

If I toggle any checkboxes for a single item, all the items in the section list rerender. thus, making the app lag a little bit.

I want to be able only to rerender the updated item.

**My Screen**

```
export const MyScreen: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {

  const [itemSelectionMode, setItemSelectionMode] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [selectedItemIDs, setSelectedItemIDs] = useState<number[]>([]);

  // I am using RTK-Query
  const {
    data: events,
    error,
    isFetching,
  } = useGetItemsQuery({
    date: someDate,
  });

  const onItemCheckBoxValueChange = (
    selected: boolean,
    itemID: number,
  ): void => {
    // toggle selected event in events.result.schedules
    if (selected) {
      setSelectedItemIDs([...selectedItemIDs, itemID]);
    } else {
      setSelectedItemIDs(selectedItemIDs.filter(id => id !== itemID));
    }
  };

  const onItemCardLongPress = (): void => {
    setItemSelectionMode(true);
  };

 const renderListItem = (item: Item): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <ListItem
        item={item}
        onLongPress={onItemCardLongPress}
        selectionMode={eventSelectionMode}
        onCheckboxValueChange={onItemCheckBoxValueChange}
        selected={selectedItemIDs.includes(item.id)}
      />
    );
  };

 const renderItemList = (): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <SectionList
        sections={items}
        renderItem={({ item }) => renderListItem(item)}
        renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => <Text>{title}</Text>}
      />
    );
  };

return (
    <View style={style.mainContainer}>
      {renderEventList()}
    </View>
);

}
```

**ListItem.tsx**

```
const renderItemDetails = (details: string) => {
  return <Text style={style.details}>{details}</Text>;
};

const renderItemAddress = (address: string) => {
  if (!address) return null;
  return <Text style={style.address}>{address}</Text>;
};

export const EventListItem: React.FC<EventListItemProps> = ({
  item,
  onLongPress,
  selectionMode = false,
  onCheckboxValueChange,
  selected = false,
}) => {
  const address = someUtilFunction(item.address);
  const details = someUtilFunction(item.boxes);

  return (
    <Card style={style.card} key={item.id} onLongPress={onLongPress}>
      // some other views
      <View style={style.headerContainer}>
        {selectionMode && (
          <Checkbox
            value={selected}
            onValueChange={(value) => {
              onCheckboxValueChange(value, item.id);
            }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
      {renderItemAddress(address)} 
      {renderItemDetails(details)}
      // some other views
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Comment: there is multiple ways to fix this, using memo everywhere sometimes is bad, i suggest read carefully this amazing blog. https://www.developerway.com/posts/react-re-renders-guide, sometimes instead of memo you can pass `{children}` prop using composition to skip children re render

Comment: @aleEspinosaM thanks for sharing a very descriptive and useful blog post. Though, I had to use memo in my case. But, I learned a lot from the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nutty suggested I had to change ListItem.tsx to

```
export const EventListItem: React.FC<EventListItemProps> = React.memo(
 ({
  item,
  onLongPress,
  selectionMode = false,
  onCheckboxValueChange,
  selected = false,
}) => {
```

as per [react documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo)

> memo lets you skip re-rendering a component when its props are unchanged.

since react uses shallow comparison to detect whether the props have changed or not, and I am passing two callback functions `onLongPress` and `onCheckboxValueChange` as props for the `ListItem.tsx`. I have to use `useCallback` hook on the above functions `onLongPress` and `onCheckboxValueChange` to result as equal in shallow comparison.

after adding the call backs the `onItemCardLongPress` will look like

```
const onItemCardLongPress = useCallback((): void => {
    setEventSelectionMode(true);
  }, [events]);
```

and the `onItemCheckBoxValueChange` will look like

```
const onItemCheckBoxValueChange = useCallback(
    (
    selected: boolean,
    itemID: number,
  ): void => {
    // toggle selected event in events.result.schedules
    if (selected) {
      setSelectedItemIDs([...selectedItemIDs, itemID]);
    } else {
      setSelectedItemIDs(selectedItemIDs.filter(id => id !== itemID));
    }
  },
    [events]
  );
```

I have found some useful topics during my endeavor,

[Be More Functional with React.memo + TypeScript](https://medium.com/@matt.huh/be-more-functional-with-react-memo-typescript-2a0e4f4833ad)

[Getting Started with React.memo()](https://blog.alexdevero.com/react-memo/)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `ListItem` with `React.memo`.
It won't re-render the item if you are expecting the props to stay the same.
Check out the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html).

I suggest you check the docs and read about react hooks like `useMemo` and `useCallback` as they can be really helpful for performance, and limiting when the component re-renders.